# Issue : Fluentd gem installation on Windows 7

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fluentd

I am facing an issue with FLUENTD gem installation.
**Issue::**

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin>gem install fluentd-0.10.32.gem  
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...  
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...  
ERROR:  Error installing fluentd-0.10.32.gem:  
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.    
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb  
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes  
checking for rb_thread_alone()... yes  
checking for rb_str_set_len()... yes  
checking for clock_gettime() in -lrt... no   
checking for sys/select.h... no  
checking for poll.h... no  
checking for sys/epoll.h... no  
checking for sys/event.h... no  
checking for port.h... no  
checking for sys/resource.h... no  
checking for sysctlbyname() in sys/param.h,sys/sysctl.h... no  
creating Makefile  
make  
generating cool.io_ext-i386-mingw32.def  
compiling cool.io_ext.c  
In file included from cool.io.h:11:0,                
from cool.io_ext.c:11:  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-  
1.9.1/ruby/backward/rubyio.h:2:2: warning: warning use "ruby/io.h"   
instead of "rubyio.h"  
.  
..  
..//Issues a lot of warnings 
.  stat_watcher.c: In function 'Coolio_StatInfo_build':  
stat_watcher.c:249:13: error: 'ev_statdata' has no member named 'st_blksize' 
stat_watcher.c:250:13: error: 'ev_statdata' has no member named 'st_blocks'  
make: *** [stat_watcher.o] Error 1  Gem files will remain installed in          
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cool.io-1.1.0 for 
inspection.  
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cool.io-1.1.0/ext/cool.io/gem_make.out 


RubyGems Environment:   
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24   
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-02-22 patchlevel 392) [i386-mingw32]  
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1  
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe  
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin  
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:  
- ruby      
- x86-mingw32   
- GEM PATHS:  
- C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1       
-  C:/Users/ssabaris/.gem/ruby/1.9.1  
- GEM CONFIGURATION:  
- :update_sources => true  
- :verbose => true  
- :benchmark => false   
- :backtrace => false  
- :bulk_threshold => 1000  
- REMOTE SOURCES:  
- http://rubygems.org/
```

**Question ::** How to sort this **cool.io** dependency issue so that I could proceed with Fluentd installation?

**Related Link ::**https://rubygems.org/gems/fluentd

Comment: Unfortunately current Fluentd doesn't support Windows.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks for the information. It is unfortunate that I didn't notice.. Can you suggest me similar tools that can run in windows?

Answer (score 0):

Log4r or Logging can be potential alternatives with a little work
and if you want to log events rather than route them to other parts 
of your application.

What is your requirement?

Comment: I am intended to perform log archiving/analytics with Mongodb as database

Comment: Mongo is storing it's documents in BSON not JSON which is a different story altogether. If you want to use mongo you will need to do it with some code of your own. If you want to store in JSON you can use CouchDB. I can write some code here to help you start if you can tell me which way you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

Fluentd doesn't run on Windows. You can use ngxlog to collect the logs from Windows to Fluentd. Please check this blog entry.

- http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/windows